# How to pass lists as variables into where in clause (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, where-clause

I am trying to make a query like this dynamic using variables in SQL Server.

**Original Query** (returns results)

```
select
*
from items
where [key] in ('material', 'type') 
and value in ('nylon/latex', 'general purpose')
```

**New Query** (returns empty set)

```
declare @keys nvarchar(max) = 'material, type'
declare @values nvarchar(max) = 'nylon/latex, general purpose'

select
*
from items
where [key] in (@keys) 
and value in (@values)
```

How can I pass CSV data into these in clauses dynamically?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089579/how-to-separate-split-string-with-comma-in-sql-server-stored-procedure
Also, if you have a fairly recent version of SQL Server (compatibility level at least 130) then you can use STRING_SPLIT function: `...where [key] in SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@keys)`

Comment: If your keys and values are all completely different then you could also try `...where @keys like '%' + [key] + '%'`